# SVG Text Mask Clipped

Tags: svg, mask, snap.svg

I'm trying to use text as a mask, and it's working for the most part. However, the very end of the text is clipped off. I'm pretty sure this is a webkit bug - the bug only appeared in Chrome and Safari, not Firefox.

I have an example [here](http://www.kaufer.org/HexText). Initially, the text is rendered as a SVG `<text>` element, and it looks as it should. Once the user clicks, I convert it to a `<mask>`, and then, as you can see, the end of the text is cut off.

Some fixes I tried, to no avail, include

- Setting the following attributes for the mask

  `"maskUnits": "userSpaceOnUse",
  "maskContentUnits": "userSpaceOnUse"`
- Giving the mask a huge viewport
- Setting the mask text width and height to 100%

None of these work. I am very confident that this is a browser bug, but I was wondering if anybody knew any fixes for it.